# command line in python with history

Tags: python, command-line

I'm writing program in python in which user is to work with program by command-line. I'm using raw_input to get command from user. I want to have "memory" like in bash, etc, so, if you press an arrow (up or down) on your keyboard, you get previous/next command. I know about one way to do it (simply get every char typed by user and check it), but maybe you know something better / cuter :-)

greetings

Comment: Why not put all the user's input in a list and tracking the command index? Something like, if they press the up arrow it decrements the command index (so we grab the previous command) and down will increment the command index.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If I understand what you want, you can achieve it simply by importing the `readline` module. This will modify the behavior of `raw_input()` so that it behaves more like the python interactive shell in terms of history and line editing.

Be careful though, it's possible to build python without `readline` so I'd suggest importing it inside a try block:

```
try:
    import readline
except:
    pass #readline not available
```

Answer (score 6):

The built-in [readline module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/readline.html) provides this functionality.